# Can Avada Kedavra be used to kill more than one being?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I am researching the capabilities and limitations of the Killing Curse in *Harry Potter* (Avada Kedavra). Can the Killing Curse be used to kill more than one? Or, is it only able to kill one foe?

Comment: This appears to be the same question as the one I closed it as a duplicate of. I closed this one because the answers to the other question cover more. (Full disclosure: one of the answers is mine.)

Answer (score 3):

The Killing Curse can only be used to kill a single individual. In plain words, if you want to "neutralize" two opponents, you need to cast it twice.

It is my understanding Avada Kedavra means immediate death, even if it hits only an arm or a leg. **Think of it as being literally touched by death**, and it is a very powerful spell.

> *"Avada Kedavra's a curse that needs a powerful bit of magic behind it — you ... them at me and say the words, and I doubt I'd get so much as a nosebleed.*"
>  — Barty Crouch Jr, disguised as Alastor Moody*.

Considering the above mentioned, I can picture three scenarios in which Avada Kedavra **could** kill more than one person at a time:

1. Two people who are holding hands are hit at the same exact spot by a single AK cast by a particularly powerful spell.
2. Siamese twins still attached to one another.
3. A pregnant woman killed along with her yet unborn child(ren).

My guess is the wizarding world doesn't exactly long for the day Wizardkind applies Muggle warfare principles to magic. This would be truly devastating. Voldemort and his followers would look like a bunch of kids throwing a tamper tantrum.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret canon as suggesting it's *possible* to kill more than one person with a curse; Peter Pettigrew killed thirteen Muggles with a single curse, an act which was subsequently blamed on Sirius Black. When Harry catches the Knight Bus in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, the conductor, Stan Shunpike, reads Harry the news about Sirius Black from the *Daily Prophet*:

> While Muggles have been told that Black is carrying a gun (a kind of metal wand which Muggles use to kill each other), the magical community lives in fear of a massacre like that of
>   twelve years ago, when **Black murdered thirteen people with a single curse**.
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 34 - Bloomsbury - chapter three, *The Knight Bus*</sub>

What it *doesn't* say -- anywhere in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, as far as I could find -- is exactly *what* curse Peter used. It's definitely possible that Peter used Avada Kedavra, because that is the classic killing curse. **DVK** pointed out to me, though, that perhaps Peter's goal all along was to cause a lethal gas line explosion that would totally wreak havoc and allow Peter to escape. In this scenario, a curse like [Incendio](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_i.html) (Incendio sets fire to something) or [Expulso](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_e.html#expulso) (Expulso is specifically a curse that blows up a target.).

I think the following passage suggests that it is *possible* for Avada Kedavra to kill more than one person at a time. In *Order of the Phoenix*, Voldemort possesses Harry in the hope that Dumbledore will kill Harry as a means to kill Voldemort:

> ‘Voldemort’s aim in possessing you, as he demonstrated tonight, would not have been my destruction. It would have been yours. **He hoped, when he possessed you briefly a short while ago, that I would sacrifice you in the hope of killing him.**’
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 730 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirty-seven, *The Lost Prophecy* - Albus Dumbledore</sub>

At this point, though, the full extent of Voldemort's Horcruxes were not known. With the Horcruxes in place, no, Voldemort would not have died. But if he had no Horcruxes, the passage suggests that both Harry and Voldemort might have been killed by Dumbledore (That is, had Dumbledore chosen to cast Avada Kedavra; Dumbledore believed there were things far worse than death.).

Also, of note, if a witch or wizard mispronounces a spell while casting it, the effects of the spell can change. In *Order of the Phoenix*, during a DA meeting, Cho Chang mispronounces Expelliarmus and sets Marietta Edgecombe's arm on fire. Could a mispronunciation of Avada Kedavra cause unusual results? Perhaps.

Comment: There wasn't _actually_ a gas explosion, was there? "**They 'ad a job coverin' it up**, din' they, Ern?" Stan said. "'Ole street blown up an' all them Muggles dead. **What was it they said 'ad 'appened**, Ern?" "Gas explosion," grunted Ernie.

Comment: @leftaroundabout -- Well, it's not really clear. All we know is the whole street was blown up and *something* caused that to happen. It's possible a curse set off a gas explosion. No, it doesn't implicitly say that, but something had to trigger it. :)

Comment: As far as OotP quote, even if it was true, it's very likely that the "killing both the host and possessing entity" isn't necessarily an Avada Kedavra thing; and ANY way of murder would have that effect. This is a pretty common trope.

Comment: @DVK - Sure, maybe so, but I think it still correctly answers the question and speaks to Avada Kedavra, trope or not :)